# Threejs lerp, lerpVectors work without animation

Tags: animation, three.js, translate-animation, lerp

I am trying to **move 10 meshes** in different directions after some amount of time through functions **lerp, lerpVectors**. Both of them gave me the same result, they just teleported meshes in new positions without **animation** of moving there. Here is my code (with "lerp"):

```
 var newPos;
 var timer = 0;
 function render() {
  if (timer === 120) {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      mesh = meshes[i];
      newPos = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() * 200 - 100, Math.random() * 200 - 100, Math.random() * 200 - 100);
      mesh.position.lerp(newPos, 0.5);
    }
  }

  timer++;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I am sure there is another way through calculated distances and then decreasing them to 0. But I suppose **lerp** and **leprVectors** do the same thing, so the question is what I do wrong?

r83

*Maybe these both functions work not as I expect.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've just figured out where was the problem. [Lerp](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3.lerp)  in the [official documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/)  looks as **.lerp(v3, alpha)** and the value **alpha** should changing dynamically, so I added [clock](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Clock):

```
var delta = clock.getDelta();
```

and **alpha** now:

```
alpha += delta;
```

also I added boolean variable to the each mesh to check whether it's enough to do **lerp** or not, moreover, I set a new position during initiating for each of them as a parameter like so:

```
mesh.newPosition = new THREE.Vector3(
      Math.random() * 200 - 100, Math.random() * 200 - 100, Math.random() * 200 - 100
    );
```

and as a result I updated my render function:

```
var timer = 0;
var alpha = 0;
var delta;
var currentX, currentY, currentZ;

function render() {
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    mesh = meshes[i];

    if (timer === 120) {
      mesh.endTransition = false;
    }

    if (!mesh.endTransition ) {
      currentX = Math.abs(mesh.newPosition.x - mesh.position.x);
      currentY = Math.abs(mesh.newPosition.y - mesh.position.y);
      currentZ = Math.abs(mesh.newPosition.z - mesh.position.z);

      if (currentX >= 1 || currentY >= 1 || currentZ >= 1) {
        alpha += delta;
        mesh.position.lerp(mesh.newPosition, alpha);
      } else {
        mesh.endTransition = true;
      }
    }
  }

  timer++;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Perhaps my solution can be improved.